# how to replace blank cell with previous cell value use python

Tags: python, csv

I want to replace blank cell to previous value in python.

Example:
data = [AAA, , ,BBB,CCC, ,DDD]

expected data = [AAA,AAA,AAA,BBB,CCC,CCC,DDD]

```
import csv

filename = 'some.csv'
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
      rows = list(csv_reader)
        print(rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Before running the code, the image of CSV file:

[image]

The code:

```
import csv

filename = 'Book1.csv'
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)
with open(filename,'w',newline='') as file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file) 
    previous=rows[0]
    for row in rows:
        if row==[]:
            csvwriter.writerow(previous)
        else:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
            previous=row
```

After running the code:

[image]

Comment: I tested with pandas but I can load the csv with empty rows :C